# SQL/Qlikview, Return all of the MAX values

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, inner-join, qlikview

I am building a report using Qlikview and I am finding difficulty populating a particular table.

In this table tbl.scores, I want to return the most recent score value for each name. on the following table

```
tbl_scores
Name    Date    Score
James   20160101    82
Simon   20160505    66
Peter   20160404    49
John    20160303    91
Sarah   20160820    68
Joe 20160202    12
James   20160921    43
Simon   20160701    77
Peter   20160319    75
John    20160905    18
Sarah   20160130    39
Joe 20160604    25
```

What I would like to have is

```
Name    Score
James   43
Simon   77
Peter   49
John    18
Sarah   68
Joe 25
```

Where I have found the MAX date for each name and returned the score.

At the moment I have had to limit it to one Name otherwise SQL does not work

Scores:
SQL

```
SELECT          
Name,
Score 
FROM       tbl_scores
WHERE
Name = 'James'
AND
Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM tbl_scores WHERE Name = 'James');
```

What would I need to change to get the desired results?

Comment: Hi there, I have 890 rows in the table and more columns. I simplified for the example. 16 distinct 'names' the query returns 176 rows rather than 16.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in QlikView instead of SQL (i.e. bring through all scores and just show those you want in this scenario) then you could use FirstSortedValue in the chart expression.

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.0/Subsystems/Client/Content/ChartFunctions/BasicAggregationFunctions/firstsortedvalue.htm

Comment: The benefit in this is that you are not losing any data in your app making future queries easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to do the same for all `Name's`

```
Select * from 
(
select row_number() over(partition by Name order by [Date] desc),*
From tbl_scores
)A
Where Rn = 1
```

Another way using `TOP 1 with Ties`

```
select TOP 1 with Ties *
From tbl_scores
Order by row_number() over(partition by Name order by [Date] desc)
```

**DEMO**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_scores
    ([Name] varchar(5), [Date] datetime, [Score] int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl_scores
    ([Name], [Date], [Score])
VALUES
    ('James', '20160101', 82),
    ('Simon', '20160505', 66),
    ('Peter', '20160404', 49),
    ('John',  '20160303', 91),
    ('Sarah', '20160820', 68),
    ('Joe',   '20160202', 12),
    ('James', '20160921', 43),
    ('Simon', '20160701', 77),
    ('Peter', '20160319', 75),
    ('John',  '20160905', 18),
    ('Sarah', '20160130', 39),
    ('Joe',   '20160604', 25)
;
```

**Result :**

```
+-------+-------------------------+-------+
| Name  |          Date           | Score |
+-------+-------------------------+-------+
| James | 2016-09-21 00:00:00.000 |    43 |
| Joe   | 2016-06-04 00:00:00.000 |    25 |
| John  | 2016-09-05 00:00:00.000 |    18 |
| Peter | 2016-04-04 00:00:00.000 |    49 |
| Sarah | 2016-08-20 00:00:00.000 |    68 |
| Simon | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 |    77 |
+-------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: This returns the desired result but has repeated rows. Eg James  43, James 43  so the results still has 12 rows rather than 6 I tried to use DISTINCT but that did not work

Comment: @KMoe  That is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Using JOINS you can do like this

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.score
FROM tbl_scores t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT name,MAX([Date]) as RecentDate
FROM tbl_scores
GROUP BY name
) t2
ON t1.[Date] = t2.[RecentDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use outer apply too:

```
  SELECT f1.name,f3.*
  FROM tbl_scores f1
  outer apply
  (
  SELECT top 1 f2.[Date], t1.score 
  FROM tbl_scores f2
  where f1.Name=f2.name
  order by f2.[Date] desc
  ) t3
```